# Find n largest nodes in an arbitrary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

Given an arbitrary tree (not a binary tree), each node is labeled an integer. 
**How can I find n largest nodes in the tree?**
e.g.
If a tree contains {43, 253, 48, 62, 91, 641}, and asked for 3 largest nodes, then the algorithm should return <641, 253, 91>.

All c++ (or any language) standard library functions/data structures are allowed.
It is also allowed to add fields to the nodes, as long as it is constant space usage. Like, I can add a field to each node to let it point to its largest child, but I cannot have an ArrayList to store all of its children in sorted order.

As a new programmer, I have spent days on this question. A simple graph search algorithm (BFS, DFS) would work and easy to implement, but they are not fast enough because they are all doing an exhaustive search on the entire tree.

Can you please help me find a correct and fast(er) solution to this problem?

Comment: If the tree is arbitrary, you probably will have to search through all the nodes anyway to find the n largest ones.

Comment: @BeLikeJo: Note that adding a field to each node to point to largest child is linear to the number of nodes.  Adding an arraylist to store all children in order is also linear to the number of nodes.  So, your restriction ("constant space usage") is a bit weird.  I'll also note that neither such field solves your problem; an arbitrary tree could end up being a unary tree, which is impossible to traverse without hitting all nodes.  I suppose there's nothing stopping each node from having child nodes unrelated to the tree, so that you're really working with two trees (one of which is binary).

Answer (score 3):

> As a new programmer, I have spent days on this question. A simple graph search algorithm (BFS, DFS) would work and easy to implement, but they are not fast enough because they are all doing an exhaustive search on the entire tree.

Since your tree is not a binary tree, examining a node does not yield an additional information about its child nodes. Therefore, it not possible to implement an algorithm that produces K highest values without an exhaustive search of the entire tree. In other words, you don't get better performance than what you'd get with an unordered array of arbitrary values.

To get K values in O(N * log K) time maintain a [priority queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) of K elements as you traverse your arbitrary tree.

Answer (score 0):

As the given tree is arbitrary with no special property. To find even 1 Highest value child, you need to search the entire graph. Complexity of it O(n).

For top K Highest value children,

You have a O(N * log K) time - a priority queue based solution, as mentioned in dasblinkenlight answer.

You have a O(N) time solution with [Median of Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) as well.